# Pass caller to a javascript function that allows me to use the .attr method

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm developing an ASP.NET MVC 5 application with C#, .NET Framework 4.7 and jQuery 1.11.

```
function RequestCodes(button, poId) {
  button.attr("disabled", "disabled");
```

That code throws an error saying the object doesn't accept `.attr` method. I call this function:

```
<input type="button" value="@Resources.RequestMoreCodes" onclick="RequestCodes(this, @Model[index].ProductionOrderId);" />
```

Maybe it is better to pass the ID instead of the object.

How can I pass the caller as a parameter to disabled it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is because the `button` variable holds an Element object, not a jQuery object. To fix this, wrap it in `$()`. Also, to disable elements it's better to use `prop()` over `attr()`.

```
function RequestCodes(button, poId) {
  $(button).prop("disabled", true);
});
```

That being said, you should avoid using the outdated `on*` event attributes. Attach unobtrusive event handlers instead. As you're already using jQuery you can do this:

```
<input type="button" class="your-button" value="@Resources.RequestMoreCodes" data-productionorderid="@Model[index].ProductionOrderId)" />
```

```js
$(function() {
  $('.your-button').click(function() {
    var $button = $(this);
    var productionOrderId = $button.data('productionorderid');

    $button.prop("disabled", true);
  });
});
```